# Error when connecting Hive with kibi?

Tags: siren

I am using `kibi-community-demo-full-4.6.4-linux-x64` version.
In datasource:

```
"connection_string": "jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/root",
"libpath": "/home/pare/Downloads/jar/",
"drivername": "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver",
"libs": "hive-jdbc-0.11.0.jar,hive-metastore-0.11.0.jar,libthrift-0.9.1.jar,hive-service-0.13.1.jar,hive-jdbc-1.2.1.2.3.2.0-2950-standalone.jar,hadoop-common-2.7.1.2.3.2.0-2950.jar",
```

After that when in queries I write a query it will show error like:

> Queries Editor: Error 400 Bad Request: Error running static method java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad URL format at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.parseURL(Utils.java:185) at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.(HiveConnection.java:84)

What is the error can any one explain me how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to connect after changing the jars version.
and also I changed the driver name "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver".